# depth $R_{\mathfrak p}=0$ implies $\mathfrak pR_{\mathfrak p}$ is associated to zero

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with unity.
I want to prove the fact that depth $R_{\mathfrak p}=0$ implies $\mathfrak pR_{\mathfrak p}$ is associated to zero.

Since depth $R_{\mathfrak p}=0$ we have that $\mathfrak pR_{\mathfrak p}$ consists of zero divisors. But to prove that it is a prime associated to $0$, I need to show that it is an annihilator ideal of some element in $R_{\mathfrak p}$.

How do I show this?

Thank you

Comment: The set of zero-divisors is the union of associated primes.

Comment: Yes. You can check Atiyah Prop. 4.7 for a reference